# Loop through table in Word and check if checkboxes are ticked

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have 4 columns, each with 2 sets of checkboxes, I was looking to loop through each set and check if both checkboxes were checked, if they are then exit the sub and put the name of the item with 2 checkboxes checked within 1 set in a msgbox.

```
Set oRow = oTable.Rows
Set oTable = doc.Tables(3)
For Each oRow In oTable.Rows
    With oRow
        If .Cells(3).Range.Text <> .Cells(3).Range.Text <> "Prep" Or .Cells(3).Range.Text <> "Y" Or .Cells(3).Range.Text <> "" Then
            If .Cells(3).ParentContentControl.Checked = True And .Cells(4).ParentContentControl.Checked = True Then 'error here
                MsgBox "The following item has both preparer and reviewer checked:" & .Cells(2)
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf .Cells(5).ParentContentControl.Checked = True And .Cell(6).ParentContentControl.Checked = True Then
                MsgBox .Cell(2)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next oRow
```

The problem is I keep on getting an error.

> Run-time error '438', object does not support this property or method.

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: Run-time error '438', object does not support this property or method.

Comment: what kind of Checkbox you have, is it `ContentControl` or `Field`? Could you add a screen shot of that part of your document for better understanding?

Comment: additionally, how did you declared your `oRow` variable? Please add more code...

Comment: I added the contentcontrol from Access: Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlCheckBox). I think I need something like If .Cells(3).Parent.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then to make sure it is a word checkbox, then I can check if it is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to `ContentControl` embedded in table, in cell, you need the following reference:

```
If .Cells(3).Range.ContentControls(1).Checked = True And .Cells(4).Range.ContentControls(1).Checked = True Then
```

Comment: Looks good, I will check, one question, I need a line to make sure that it does not try the line of code when the cell does not contain a checkbox. Something like If .Cells(3).Parent.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox would you have any ideas?

Comment: try something like this: `If .cells(3).range.contentcontrols.count >1 then` to check if any CC exists...